# Finding NLS for multiple series

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I want to fit a model /find a functional form using 70 series. I have 30 values for each one of them.  The plot shows that the trend is not linear so I am  trying to use NLS. [image: the data looks like this]

Not sure if this is the right approach. I have not implemented this before. Should I be using something else to model? I am getting the following error:

> Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(b * x), start = list(a = a_start, b = b_start)) :
>       singular gradient

x has values 1:30, which are repeated 70 times. Y values vary between  0 and 1. Should I be using 71 vectors (of length 30) or should I gather them all in two columns. At  the moment, I have gathered them all in two columns.

The data looks something like this:

---

[image]

```
a_start<-0.2
b_start<-2*log(2)/a_start
```

Comment: I'm relatively inexperienced with `nls`, but from the times I've used it, one of the trickiest parts is to feed it starting values that are close enough so that it can find a solution. I am not sure if this error is related, but this will be a problem for trying to automate fitting many series. For this, you might look into the self starting models. See `?selfStart` and the links.

Comment: Try taking the log of both sides and fitting that using lm and then transforming the result into starting values or maybe the lm is sufficient on its own for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your formula is not a form that accurately reflects your data.  y ~ a * exp(b * x) will never look like your data, so you'll get sharp gradients that don't make any sense.

Try this:

```
#some made up data, since none provided
x <- runif(1000) * 30
y <- -0.9 * exp(-0.5 * x) + 1.1 + rnorm(length(x), sd=0.1)

fit <- nls(y ~ a * exp(b * x) + c, start = list(a = -1, b=-.1, c=1))

plot(x,y)
lines(x[order(x)], predict(fit)[order(x)], col="red", lwd=4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @thc. I understand, that the error was because of the incorrect function. Using the function you have specified, I do get a fit. I want the start to be close to 0.2. Probably, I need to play with the parameters to achieve the desired results.

Comment: @NKaz, glad it helped.  The function I suggested was just an example based on the shape of your data.  I suggest trying to find out an equation that makes sense from a scientific perspective.  All the parameters in the model should have a scientific meaning.

Comment: could you suggest any read/link on scientifically finding nonlinear  equations using the data. I did try using the log of y values and apply lm. But the residuals are auto correlated. Other things I have tried are nls2 (brute force). But it is about finding a better parameter values - based on the formula I specify.

Comment: I mean to determine an equation based on what generated your data, not the data itself.  If you didn't see the data yet, what kind of model would you think appropriate?  I can't give you any suggestions without knowing what your project is about.

Comment: Its sales data from Google Analytics. The conversion values change (mainly increase) over a period of 30 days. I have a historical dataset of the reported conversion values on day 1 up to day 30 and I want to develop a model  to predict (with some CI) what the increase will be after 30 days. I am trying to model the daily difference, instead of the actual sales value.  As I shown on the graph, most of the change happens during day1-day10. Since different markets behave differently, I am trying to develop model each market separately.